# How to get a color image in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, uiimage

I want something as follows

```
UIImage *solid = [UIImage imageWithColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
```

to create an image with respect to some color.

how to do it in iPhone sdk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can draw the color into a CGContext and then capture an image from it:

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size {
  //Create a context of the appropriate size
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
  CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

  //Build a rect of appropriate size at origin 0,0
  CGRect fillRect = CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height);

  //Set the fill color
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, color.CGColor);

  //Fill the color
  CGContextFillRect(currentContext, fillRect);

  //Snap the picture and close the context
  UIImage *retval = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(void);
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return retval;
}
```

Comment: I think there is some method which makes it easy than drawing it.
I saw it sometime while surfing but dint remember it. Thought of posting it here if anybody knows it.

Comment: Drawing it is ~7 lines you can wrap in a convenience method, I don't see it getting much easier, it is not exactly a common function.

Comment: Consider UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); instead of UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(void);

Answer (score 2):

If you're just trying to create a solid rectangle of colour why not just do something like

```
UIView *solid = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
solid.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```

And then add the view to whatever subview you want to show the solid colour.

(That is, of course only if that's what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you aren't)