# UINavigationBar with solid color iOS 5

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, customizing

I'm using the category to customize nav bar. My code is:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([self.tintColor CGColor]));
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
```

It works well, but not in iOS 5. I need nav bar color to be solid without any gradient. How should I do this?

As I know, for iOS 5 the only way to replace `drawRect` method is to make a subclass, but is there any way to make all navigation controllers to use `UINavigationBar` subclass instead of original class?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In iOS 5 you can use the UIAppearance protocol to set the appearance of all UINavigationBars in your app. Reference: [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance).

The way I got a solid color was to create a custom image for the navigation bar, and set it as UINavigationBars background. You might have to create the image with the same size as the UINavigationBar, at least that's what I did.

In your app delegate, do something like this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navbarbg.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

You also have to add the `UIAppearanceContainer` protocol to the header file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UIAppearanceContainer>

@end
```

You can probably achieve the same thing by setting some color or something, instead of an image. But I found this to be an easy solution.

Comment: Is this supposed to work with solid color? It does''t look like it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "solid color"? At least it works with `tintColor`. You can see in the header files of the UIKit framework which properties and methods that are supported by the `UIAppearance` protocol. The supported ones have `UI_APPEARANCE_PROTOCOL` written at the end of their line. Take the `UINavigationBar` as an example: it has 6 properties/methods that are supported.

Comment: I get a 2 px offset when I use this solution. It appears as a very thin black line at the top of the screen. How can I solve that? Otherwise this is a great answer since it doesn't rely on overriding navigation bar

Comment: @Hgeg, that sounds weird.. Are you using an image for the background? Check that the image has the same size as the navigation bar.

Comment: @matsr Yup. that was my problem. The image ratio was different from navbar size. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Instead of creating an actual image asset, you can create one programatically, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1213816/883413

Answer (score 1):

This covers both iOS 5 and iOS 4.3 and earlier

https://gist.github.com/1774444

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a hack and has consistently worked for me.
This needs to be in the AppDelegate file.

```
//Create  a size struct.
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(768, 50);

//CReate a imagecontext from a non-existing image. You can use a existing image as well, in that case the color will be the color of the image. 
UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nonexist.png"];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

[backgroundImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height)];

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
```

Set the background color to be the color of your choice.

```
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//Most important line.
[navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage: newImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```