# How to change UINavigationBar background color from the AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I know how to change the `UINavigationBar` background image by doing

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nabbar"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and I know how to set the bar to different colors within each `Views`..... Now I want to change the background color *without using an image* to a solid color from the `app delegate`. I do not want to set it each time from each view and I do not want to write a `CGRect`.

I tried  `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:33/255.0 green:34/255.0 blue:36/255.0 alpha:1.0]];` but I doesn't work and I cant find a code anywhere that works in the app delegate.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can use `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];`

Since iOS 7 you need to set `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myColor];` and also `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]`.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myColor];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to remove the white default gradient that comes from the top to make it a solid color?

Comment: With `tintColor` the gradient will stay. If you don't want to have this gradient, you need to subclass your UINavigationBar OR to make an UIImage for the appearance.

Comment: on iOS 7 that didn't work, I had to use `navigationBar.barTintColor = myColor;`

Comment: `translucent` property just can't be set using UIAppearance in iOS 6 and iOS 7. So `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO]` will crash the app with `NSInvalidArgumentException` error. Use `[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO]` or deselect transparency using IB.

Comment: Swift Version: 
`UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = myColor`
`UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false`

Answer (score 105):

To change the background color and not the tint the following piece of code will work:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, works perfectly for iOS7.

Comment: Correct answer for iOS 7. Working for me.

Comment: The translucency is the requirement to make this work. As the accepted answer doesn't include that, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Just to clarify, the accepted answer is for AppDelegate and this is for within the View Controller.

Comment: @Dean is right. Accepted answer will take effect for newly created `UIViewControllers`, while this one will show effects whenever is called.

Comment: works for iOS 9.3        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString:"#a71428")

Answer (score 19):

For doing this in iOS 7:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:myColor];
```

Answer (score 16):

**Swift syntax:**

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor() //changes the Bar Tint Color
```

I just put that in the AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and it persists throughout the app

Answer (score 12):

**iOS 13.0** introduced new API for this:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let myColor = UIColor(hue: 0.4, saturation: 0.25, brightness: 1, alpha: 1)
    
    let barAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    barAppearance.backgroundColor = myColor

    let navigationBar = UINavigationBar.appearance()
    navigationBar.standardAppearance = barAppearance
    navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = barAppearance // for scrollable content or large titles
    
    return true
}
```

[image: navigation bar]

- [UINavigationBarAppearance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbarappearance)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift**:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```

Answer (score 6):

You can easily do this with Xcode 6.3.1. Select your NavigationBar in the Document outline. Select the Attributes Inspector. Uncheck Translucent. Set Bar Tint to your desired color. Done!

Comment: Thanks, I found lots of references on how to do this in ObjC and swift, but noone mentioning its available in IB

Answer (score 3):

As the other answers mention, you can use `setTintColor:`, but you want a solid color and that's not possible to do setting the tint color AFAIK.

The solution is to create an image programmatically and set that image as the background image for all navigation bars via `UIAppearance`. About the size of the image, I'm not sure if a 1x1 pixel image would work or if you need the exact size of the navigation bar.Check the second answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266182/uinavigationbar-with-solid-color-ios-5) to see how to create the image.

As an advice, I don't like to "overload" the app delegate with these type of things. What I tend to do is to create a class named `AppearanceConfiguration` with only one public method `configureAppearance` where I set all the UIAppearance stuff I want, and then I call that method from the app delegate.

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1

You can change your navigation bar colour from your AppDelegate directly to your entire project.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:` write below to lines of code

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 96/255, blue: 130/255, alpha: 1.0)
```

Here

**tintColor** is for to set background images like back button & menu lines images etc. (See below left and right menu image)

**barTintColor** is for navigation bar background colour

If you want to set specific view controller navigation bar colour, write below code in `viewDidLoad()`

```
//Add navigation bar colour
navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 2/255, green: 96/255, blue: 130/255, alpha: 1.0)
navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

[image]

Comment: it was useful for me. thank @Naresh

Answer (score 2):

You can set UINavigation Background color by using this code in any view controller

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:10.0f/255.0f green:30.0f/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
```

Answer (score -1):

The colour code is the issue here. Instead of using 195/255, use 0.7647 or 195.f/255.f The problem is converting the float is not working properly. Try using exact float value.