# Change color of navigation bar title

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to style the `UINavigationBar` in `Xamarin` with `MonoTouch`. In the constructor of the `UIViewController` I tried the following:

```
//this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Magenta;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.Yellow;
```

But if I try to run this in the simulator there is nothing changed. Where should I place this code? How do I use a RGB color (with `UIColor.FromRGB (0, 127, 14)`?) Is my code correct?

Comment: Already tried my solution? Got it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution:

```
//AppDelegate.cs
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    // class-level declarations
    UIWindow window;
    public static UIStoryboard Storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("MainStoryboard", null);
    public static UIViewController initialViewController;

    // ...
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        initialViewController = Storyboard.InstantiateInitialViewController () as UIViewController;

        UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes (
            new UITextAttributes () { TextColor = UIColor.FromRGB (0, 127, 14) });

        window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're developing for iOS7 you need to set BarTintColor.

```
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.Red;
UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 127, 14);
```

see: [How to change UINavigationBar background color from the AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-app-delegate)

Put this code in AppDelegate.cs

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
NSDictionary *textTitleOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor darkGrayColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:textTitleOptions];
```

Or you can refer more from 
[IOS 7 Navigation Bar text and arrow color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029833/ios-7-navigation-bar-text-and-arrow-color)

Comment: Do you also have a solution for `Xamarin`? Here `C#` is used. Where should this code go?

Answer (score 0):

You should specific the `UIViewController`, like:

```
viewController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

or in `UIViewController`:

```
self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
```

Comment: Perhaps it was not clear enough - I need that for `C#`. The notation here is different ...

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that