# Change ios8 Extension Navigation Bar color

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I am working on iOS8 App Extension (Photo Editing Extension)

I have tried these method to update the Navigation Bar color, but failed:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

It displays a default translucent gray nav bar.

[image: default nav. color]

Does anybody have idea on how to change the navigation bar color in iOS8 extension?

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible?

Comment: Not yet. @SausageMachine

Comment: Calling UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor works and changes the color, but that doesn't extend to the status bar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39000941/how-to-apply-the-navigation-bar-color-to-the-status-bar-in-an-extension

Answer (score 10):

Try `self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellow` first.
This should work for some host apps but not all. Because some host apps configure the colors in UIAppearance settings.

I found some info in here: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/action-extension/#uiappearance
According to the link above, the extension will "picks up the UIAppearance settings from its host app" and this has a higher priority than the "setColor" message you send to the instance.

In this case what you can do is to modify the plist of the extension:
In `NSExtension` dictionary you can add a key `NSExtensionOverridesHostUIAppearance` and set value to `YES`. This will make your extension override the UIApprearance setting of the host app. Unfortunately this is only available in iOS 10 and later.

Hope you find it helpful.

Comment: this should be marked as correct answer - `NSExtensionOverridesHostUIAppearance` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the translucency of the `UINavigationBar` to `NO` like below, I believe then it should start picking up the colours

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTranslucent:NO];
```

Here's the [Apple Documentation for `UINavigationBar` `translucent` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uinavigationbar_class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW10)

Comment: It does not work.. I think the problem is `[UINavigationBar appearance]` isn't the way to access the title bar in extension..

Comment: @DavidNg Try `[[[[self navigationController] navigationBar] appearance] setTranslucent:NO];` and replace the rest of them with the same.

Comment: [[self navigationController] navigationBar] does not have appearance property, appearance is a instanceType from `UINavigationBar` class.

Comment: @DavidNg balls yeah forgot sorry. What happens when you try setting it directly and not using `appearance`?

Comment: Not working. I guess it might be the navigation bar is not accessed in this way

Comment: This confuses me because I don't believe they have changed anything around this going from iOS7 to iOS8 so your code should really work also see these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-app-delegate and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929864/how-to-change-navigation-bar-color-in-ios-7

Comment: Yes, but i think it's because it's contained as an extension.
Thanks for your keen respond @Popeye!

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same case as Action Extension. It isn't possible to change navigation bar the same way as well. I had to use the old method of changing the navigation bar background color. Appearance methods, barTintColor, does not work. It's as though it's running a few OS version behind.

Comment: @honcheng It does seem odd that this doesn't work I have also tried this code since answering and it doesn't work using appearance but I can set it doing it the other way still seems like a bit of a bug to me but I can live with it.

Answer (score -2):

I have put your code in the appDelegate didFinishLaunchWithOption

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    return YES;
}
```

And works...

[image]

Comment: This works for main portion of app, but does not work for extensions.