# How to apply the navigation bar color to the status bar in an extension?

Tags: ios, swift

If within an action extension I change the color of the navigation bar as follows:

```
class ActionViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Then the result looks like this, with the status bar in white:

[image]

But if the same line (`UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor`) is applied to an application (as opposed to an extension) then the result is different, for example if the following line is added to the XCode master-detail template project:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Then this is the result with the status bar also green:

[image]

How can I get the status bar to appear green in the action extension?

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34658477/1378447) let us know the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the default `ActionViewController` use a `UINavigationBar` without UINavigationController.If you check the storyboard of `ActionViewController`,you can see the `UINavigationBar` is 20 points shorter than when it's used in a UINavigationController.

The view behind the statusBar is the rootView not the NavigationBar.

The solution is :

1.change your viewController structure to include a UINavigationController.

2.add a statusBarBackgroundview below statusbar,and change it's color :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

   UIView* statusBarBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
   statusBarBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

   [self.view insertSubview:statusBarBackgroundView atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, SO won't let me award the bounty yet, I'll do so when it does.