# NavigationBar & BarButtonItem color change for MessageComposer presented on choosing from UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am sharing a text using UIActivityViewController,
And on choosing "Message" from the options listed my screen appears as follows,
[image]

But there is a cancel button at right bar button which is white color as assigned in my AppDelegate.
The problem here is I cannot able to update NavigationBar color.

I have tried as follows and none was useful,

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: contents, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityVC, animated: true) {
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        activityVC.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
        MYAppDelegate.customise()
    }
```

or

```
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: contents, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activityVC, animated: true) { 
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.red
        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        let navigationTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = navigationTextAttributes
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(navigationTextAttributes, for: .normal)
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

How to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is sharing some content thru `share extension`[1](what you showed in the picture) of iOS message app which is developed by Apple. So basically Apple has control on the color of it.

Here is a link of my previous answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42517419/5220959 I haven't tried yet but I think you can try to change the `UIAppearance settings` of your host app and see if that works. But in that way all navigation bars' color will be changed in your host app.

[1]https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#