# How to change UINavigationBar color globally?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change UINavigationBar color globally for the whole application from the AppDelegate. For it I do:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(red: 63, green: 172, blue: 236, alpha: 1)
}
```

but, I do not know why, it doesn't change the color of my Navigation bar.

I had connect Navigation Bar as `Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller`

How can I set the color for NavBar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change UINavigationBar background color from the app delegate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-app-delegate)

Comment: You just forgot to divide with 255 and use the barTintColor to set color for navigation bar. I have added a answer. Hope it helps

Answer (score 30, accepted):

set `barTintColor`

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 63.0/255.0, green: 172.0/255.0, blue: 236.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

I think you forgot to divide with 255

For turn off the `translucent`. In your first root controller do it as follows.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.translucent = false
}
```

**Swift 3 :**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

My output:

[image]

Comment: but how can I disable transparentness of the bar?

Comment: when I try `navigationBar.translucent = false` it makes it white =/

Comment: I try `UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = false` and it gives me white bar

Comment: For Xcode 8, there is no .barTintColor anymore. It has only something like this: UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor and it does not work.
Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: @VaVisal No. The barTintColor working with Swift 3 and Xcode 8. only tintColor is used for color of bar button items.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

Comment: create property for navigationController in appdelegate.h and connect to your navigationController

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
Objective C:

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

Swift:

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
```

It will make you navigation bar with yellow color.

PS : Don't use tintColor, tint color is for back buttons titles.

A navigation bar has other properties as well. 
You can check them on Apple site as well   & can apply solutions as per your need.

> https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uinavigationbar