# Segment control background color not getting changed

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am working on a project where I am using custom buttons for login and signup.
All I want is when I click on login, the color of signup button changes and when I click on signup button again the color of login button changs back.

I tried the following code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // [self.view setNuiClass:@"ViewInit"];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        img.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-4-apple-logo-wallpapers-set-2-05.jpg"];
        [self.view addSubview:img];
        NSLog(@"Height Pro %f",[[DeviceClass instance] getResizeScreen:NO].size.height);
        scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[DeviceClass instance] getResizeScreen:NO]];
        scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;
        scrollView.delegate = self;
        [self.view addSubview:scrollView];


        segmentControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[NSLocalizedString(@"profile_tab_signin", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"profile_tab_signup", nil)]];
        segmentControl.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
        segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
        [segmentControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [scrollView addSubview:segmentControl];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        //Init
        [self autoLogin];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];


        //[signUpBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        //[loginBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    }


  - (void)valueChanged
    {

        //For SignIn/SignUp

        if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
        {

            [usernameSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [emailSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [firstNameSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [lastNameSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [passwordSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [retypepasswordSignUp removeFromSuperview];
            [signUpBtn removeFromSuperview];

            //[signUpBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [self signInForm];
        }

        else
        {
             [lostPassword removeFromSuperview];
            [username removeFromSuperview];
            [password removeFromSuperview];
            [loginBtn removeFromSuperview];
            [self signUpForm];

        }
    }
```

Please suggest me some useful code as I am new in iOS.

Comment: in this button place r u used segment control

Comment: yes by default its color shows blue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17014723/4475605

Comment: see this link may be helps you https://goddess-gate.com/dc2/index.php/post/454

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it more easily readable. You may want to use the shift button a little more when writing questions!

Comment: Can you add the code where you create login and signup the buttons? Also, you are trying to change background color of buttons that you are removing from superview and they are probably getting deallocated.