# Change UI tab bar icons display color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Change `UITabBar` icons display color.
Here are the screenshots,

Tab bar icons display color is gray.
[image]

I want to change the UI tab bar icons into white. How can I implement this? I tried already in storyboard "User define runtime attributes" set key path "selectedImage". But it doesn't work.

Change `UITabBar` icons display into white.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkNgs.png]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-appdelegate I think this helps..sorry in advance if not

Comment: What exactly are you setting now to have gray?  What images are you using - are they transparent?

Comment: To have white UI tab bar icons, I'm using the white images only :)

Comment: Put tab bar tint color white color

Comment: Solved. Thank you guys :)