# Change the color of iOS Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to change the color of my navigator bar but I found that it's only impossible if the navigator is the root one.

I'm trying this:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = true

self.navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

All my `Viewcontrollers` are related to navigator controllers. However nothing is changed. In fact I tried to make the same things from storyboard but it works only if I'm in the first navigator.

I tried to read everything related to this problem but found nothing

I could add any item to the navigator bar like this

```
let HomeImage = UIImage(named: "home")!
    let Home : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: HomeImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "home:")
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Home
```

Comment: For latest answer see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014713/how-to-change-uinavigationbar-background-color-from-the-appdelegate/55391324#55391324

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In fact, i found that the solution was to use in the `AppDelegate.siwft` :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    return true
}
```

and then in each view controller, that we need another background color or something else

1. the segue should be different than "show"
2. use the func `viewWillAppear`

   ```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]
   }
   ```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't makes seamless transition between two controller

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier 'NSForegroundColorAttributeName'

Comment: @Takasur for swift 4 use, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor

Comment: And also make sure you don't have a background image (which covers the background color) in your navigation bar. I had mine there accidentally set by someone else and it cost me couple hours to check it out...

Comment: @Anthony I got an other problem. This successful change the title text color. But if push another view controller then return back, the title text color still not changed.

Answer (score 55):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

**Swift 4**

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

**Swift 5**

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

Comment: do i have to do this in appdelegate.siwft file ?

Comment: func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // setup navBar.....
    }

Comment: @PrashannaChudal yes, u can.. code this in above appdelegate method (see above comment)..

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 4.2**:

```
    //To change Navigation Bar Background Color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
    //To change Back button title & icon color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    //To change Navigation Bar Title Color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

**Swift 3.x**:

```
//To change Navigation Bar Background Color
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.blue
//To change Back button title & icon color
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
//To change Navigation Bar Title Color
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: Swift 4.2, use `NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor` instead.

Comment: For some weird reason, the auto-completion in Xcode 10 was not proposing barTintColor as a property of UINavigationBar.appearance(), but copy/pasting your code did compile and work. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

For changing the navigation bar theme color throughout the full app you can do this by using UiNavigation bar appearance.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 4):

If your view controller is embedded in navigation controller then you can remove this default navigation bar and can use a custom navigation bar for that view controller.

Then you can do look like

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 46.0/255.0, green: 14.0/255.0, blue: 74.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Answer (score 4):

Make the following update to the AppDelegate.Swift file i.e.
`UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:x.xx, green:x.xx, blue:x.xx, alpha:1.0)`

Refer to example below

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.03, green:0.25, blue:0.11, alpha:1.0)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white]
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.gray
```

Answer (score 1):

For black nav bar try this:

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
```

Comment: this only change style, not bar color. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

solving this issue for SwiftUI:

```
            init() {
        //         For .navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .automatic)
        
        let coloredAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        coloredAppearance.backgroundColor = .black
        coloredAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        // to make everything work normally
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = coloredAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = coloredAppearance
        
        //         For .navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .inline)
        
        //        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
        //        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            //                     Text("Screen")
            let HomeImage = UIImage(named: "home")!
            let Home : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: HomeImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "home:")
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = Home
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Update"), displayMode: .automatic)
        }
        // that means only show one view at a time no matter what device I'm working
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
```