# Going to next view changes the navigation bar background color

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

When i am presenting new view using push method then for a little time little portition of my navigation bar color changes due to it it shows dark blue at that portition and then get back to light color.

As shown in the image.

How should i fix this effect

[image: navigation bar background color changes]

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0/255, blue: 205/255, alpha: 1)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()]

    return true
}
```

or Can set in viewcontroller

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blueColor()]

}
```

more detail and credit: [Swift - iOS : Change the color of a Navigation Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931463/swift-ios-change-the-color-of-a-navigation-bar)

Hope this help