# View rendered into context results in empty image

Tags: c#, ios, uiview, xamarin

**I am trying to create a bitmap copy of a view to use it as a drag shadow for a drag & drop operation.**

I have used the techniques described here:

[How to capture UIView to UIImage without loss of quality on retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334233/how-to-capture-uiview-to-uiimage-without-loss-of-quality-on-retina-display)

[How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214957/how-do-i-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-uiview)

[How to get a color image in iPhone sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213790/how-to-get-a-color-image-in-iphone-sdk) (to render a solid fill into the view, resulted in an empty image too)

**But the result is always a transparent/empty image** (it's not nil/null, I checked)

The views I'm trying to copy contain (transparent) SVGs.

Here is my code:

```
    // always results in an fully transparent/empty image
    private UIView CreateDragShadow(UIView view)
    {
        UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(view.Bounds.Size, false, 0.0f);
        CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
        //view.DrawViewHierarchy(view.Bounds, true);    // "old" way
        view.Layer.RenderInContext(context);            // recommended way

        UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        UIImageView dropShadow = new UIImageView();
        dropShadow.Image = image;

        return dropShadow;
    }
```

I have also written a little test function to see if the view gets added to the superview correctly, which works and correctly produces a white UIView with "Drag shadow" written on it:

```
    // this produces a white drag shadow image with "Drag shadow" written on it
    private UIView CreateDragShadowTest(UIView view)
    {
        // test with a simple UITextView to see if the approach works
        UITextView viewTestShadow = new UITextView(view.Frame);
        viewTestShadow.Bounds = view.Bounds;
        viewTestShadow.Text = "Drag shadow";

        return viewTestShadow;
    }
```

Does anybody know what's going on?

I'm also open to entirely different ways of doing this.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I have since found an answer on the Xamarin documentation page that I couldn't find mentioned anywhere else when searching SO

The new code is:

```
    private UIView CreateDragShadow(UIView view)
    {                
        UIView dropShadow = view.SnapshotView(true);
        return dropShadow;
    }
```

Which exposes snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates (found here: [Apple Doc snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:)) and conveniently produces a UIView snapshot.

This solution has worked for me, but I would still like to know what I was doing wrong with the other approaches, if anybody knows.